# What does the search on chat actually index?

Tags: support, chat, search

I was trying to find [a URL I posted yesterrday](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16052134#16052134) and performed the following search: https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=right-arrow&user=&room=118

But I don't get the desired result. Why? Are URLs not being indexed?

Comment: URLs are indexed, because I can find it if I search for "right-arrow.net" and not for "right-arrow".

Comment: ah, lexers and stemmers, y u so crazy?

Comment: @ProgramFOX So it only matches full "words"?

Comment: It looks like it does, but I don't know it for sure.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22right-arrow.net%22&user=&room=118 finds it. Your query is being parsed and stemmed; parsed out into individual words, stemmed to match plural forms, etc.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I note that `*` wildcards don't appear to help?